# colspan problem

Tags: html, html5

Как поднять 17ую ячейку до середины 11ой, чтобы ничего не съехало?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Мондриан</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1" width="450px" cellspacing="0" style="border: 3px solid black; margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="background:#BACED7">1</td>
      <td colspan="1" style="background:#D0DAD9">2</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="background:#E6CD2D">3</td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="background:#C6D8E2">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td row style="background:#D0DADB">5</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="200px" style="background: #E4260A; color: black;">6</td>
      <td colspan="2" height="100px" style="background: #C5A402; color: black;">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background:#BED1D8">8</td>
      <td height="120px" width="75px" style="background: #B6B6B8; color: black;">9</td>
      <td height="120px" width="75px" style="background: #B6B6B8; color: black;">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" height="120px" style="background: #212528; color: white;">11</td>
      <td height="60px" style="background: #979DAA; color: black; ">12</td>
      <td colspan="2" height="50px" style="background: #ADB1B4; color: black;">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background: #989EA6; color: black;">14</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background: #163255; color: white;">15</td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="background: #C83829">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="background: #D0B51C">17</td>
      <td rowspan="2" height="40px" style="background: #A7A7A5; color: black;">18</td>
      <td style="background: #1F2020; color: white;">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="3" style="background:#C8D5D5">20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот

А можно поинтересоваться, что это Вы такое делаете?

```html
<table border="1" width="450px" cellspacing="0" style="border: 3px solid black; margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="background:#BACED7">1</td>
    <td colspan="1" style="background:#D0DAD9">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="background:#E6CD2D">3</td>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background:#C6D8E2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td row style="background:#D0DADB">5</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="200px" style="background: #E4260A; color: black;">6</td>
    <td colspan="2" height="100px" style="background: #C5A402; color: black;">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background:#BED1D8">8</td>
    <td height="120px" width="75px" style="background: #B6B6B8; color: black;">9</td>
    <td height="120px" width="75px" style="background: #B6B6B8; color: black;">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" height="120px" style="background: #212528; color: white;">11</td>
    <td height="60px" style="background: #979DAA; color: black; ">12</td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px" style="background: #ADB1B4; color: black;">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" style="background: #D0B51C">17</td>
    <td style="background: #989EA6; color: black;">14</td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background: #163255; color: white;">15</td>
    <td rowspan="3" style="background: #C83829">16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" height="40px" style="background: #A7A7A5; color: black;">18</td>
    <td style="background: #1F2020; color: white;">19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="3" style="background:#C8D5D5">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Композицю Мондриана "Композиция с Красным, Желтым, Синим и Черным"

Comment: @Jevgewa, это ради искусства или ради практики работы с таблицами?

Comment: ради практики :D